# Change parent's class with jQuery

Tags: jquery

There are dropdown groups for certain links. This is the part of them:

If the li has active-item class under level-1, then i try to replace parent li's close-item with open-item.

This is jquery code for this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.active-item').parent('li').addClass('open-item').removeClass('close-item');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="has-child-item close-item">
  <a><i class="fa fa-cubes" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>İstasyon Ayarları</span></a>
  <ul class="nav child-nav level-1">
    <li class="active-item"><a href="{{url('/istasyonlar')}}">İstasyon Listesi</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{url('/istasyonlar/ekle')}}">Yeni İstasyon Tanımlama</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

But it's not working.

Comment: `$('.active-item').closest("li.close-item").addClass('open-item').removeClass('close-item');` try this one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.active-item is not a parent of li it IS the li, you want:

```
.closest("li.close-item")
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this :

```
$('.active-item').parents().closest('li').addClass('open-item').removeClass('close-item');
```

it will change the closest li

Answer (score 1):

Using [closest()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp)

> closest() selects the first element that matches the selector, up from
>   the DOM tree.

FYI [parent()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_parent.asp)

> parent() selects one element up the DOM tree.

**Solution**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.active-item').closest('li.has-child-item').toggleClass('open-item close-item');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="has-child-item close-item">
  <a><i class="fa fa-cubes" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>İstasyon Ayarları</span></a>
  <ul class="nav child-nav level-1">
    <li class="active-item"><a href="{{url('/istasyonlar')}}">İstasyon Listesi</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{url('/istasyonlar/ekle')}}">Yeni İstasyon Tanımlama</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent of .active-item is a UL not an LI. The LI you are looking for is the parent of that parent.